# How to run artisan command in bash script outside laravel?

Tags: laravel, bash, symfony

I am using two frameworks i.e. Laravel and Symfony for two applications which are interlinked with each other. Both are having bash script.

Now, I want to write 'php artisan down' command in Symfony's bash script so that if I merge code to Symfony then both the applications gets down.

How can I write Laravel artisan command in Symfony framework?

Answer (score 1):

It should work like any other command:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
php /full/project/path/artisan down
```

Just write the full path.

Comment: Ok, also I want to write Symfony 'sudo supervisorctl stop all' in laravel bash script. How to do that

Comment: Just add the command to the script below the artisan, but you can't sudo inside of a bash script, the whole bash script must be run as superuser.

Answer (score 1):

#### You can do this in your Symfony project using [Symfony Console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console.html):

```
//in your symfony project
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;


public function processCmd() {
    $process = new Process('php /absolute/path/to/project/artisan down');
    $process->run();
    if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
        throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
    }
    echo $process->getOutput();
}
```

#### Update:

Laravel also uses the same symfony's Console component!
So if you want to run something in Laravel, you can use the same code above.

**Example:**

```
    //in your laravel project 
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
    use Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException;
    
    
    public function processCmd() {
        $process = new Process('supervisorctl stop all');
        $process->run();
        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        echo $process->getOutput();
    }
```

**P.S:**

You can pass an array if you want to run multiple commands:

```
 $process = new Process(array('ls', '-lsa'));
```

Comment: I want all these in bash script.